# How to make prompt repeat if input is NaN

Tags: javascript, prompt, nan

I have this quick code snippet:

```
var sQuantity = 0
if (sQuantity = 0 || isNaN(sQuantity)) {
  (sQuantity = parseInt(prompt("Let's begin compiling our student database. How many students would you like to enter?", "Number of Students")));
  (sQuantity = 1);
}
```

But when I run it like this, the prompt doesn't come up at all. Obviously I'm mistaken how this should work. How do I get a prompt to keep popping up if an Integer is not entered? I'm probably going about this all wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
var sQuantity;
do {
  sQuantity = parseInt(prompt('Prompt message', 'Default prompt value'), 10);
} while (!sQuantity);
```

The code shown in your question is wrong by two reasons. First, you don't actually check for `sQuantity` being equal to 0 - you *assign* 0 to it (with `= 0`; should've been `== 0` at least). To be precise, actually assigned is the result of `0 || isNaN(sQuantity)`. And it's `false` - as `sQuantity` is equal to 0 at the moment of assignment, not `NaN`.

But even more important is the second flaw: there's no sense checking for `sQuantity` value with `if` right after you assigned a some value to it. You do know that it's equal to 0, right?

The only case when it makes sense is when you use a **loop**: first assigning some value to the variable (as result of `prompt`), then checking this value in the loop's condition.

In my example I've used `do-while` loop, as you obviously have to show `prompt` to a user at least once. With `!sQuantity` clause I check for both `NaN` and `0`: these are the only falsy values that could be returned by `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest working code I can make:

```js
var nbr;
while (isNaN(nbr = prompt("message", "test")));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rh2Uq/1/